# NoMethodError : undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to follow the tutorial Searching and Buying Twilio Phone Numbers here -->http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/search-and-buy

For now, All I want to do is to list the available phone numbers. Right now I have a find_numbers controller, with new, create, destroy.

The New Action has paramaters which the user fills out, and the create action renders the show, and the show is supposed to put it all together, and list the numbers.

However, with the code that I have, I get the error

```
NoMethodError in Find_numbers#create

Showing C:/Sites/dct/app/views/find_numbers/show.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I think it's because my @numbers variable is returning nil, because the search parameters aren't set correctly.

Here's my view for the new action :

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_tag("/find_numbers", :method => "post" ) do %>

      <%= label_tag(:in_postal_code, "Near US postal code (e.g. 94117):") %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:in_postal_code) %>

      <%= label_tag(:near_number, "Near this other number (e.g. +4156562345)") %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:near_number) %>

      <%= label_tag(:contains, "Matching this pattern (e.g. 415***EPIC):") %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:contains) %>  

      <%= submit_tag("Search", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary") %>


    <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is the find_numbers controller

```
class FindNumbersController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @user = current_user
    end

    def create
        @user = current_user
        render 'find_numbers/show'
    end

    def show
        @user = current_user
        client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@user.twilio_account_sid, @user.twilio_auth_token)

        search_params = {}
          %w[in_postal_code near_number contains].each do |p|
            search_params[p] = params[p] unless params[p].nil? || params[p].empty?
        end

        local_numbers = client.account.available_phone_numbers.get('US').local
        @numbers = local_numbers.list(search_params)    


    end

end
```

And this, is the show view

```
<%= number.friendly_name %>
<%= number.phone_number %>
```

I'm getting closer to the answer since this morning(China time), but still running around in circles! Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to learn a little more about rails. The book I used to get started is http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails

What you are doing right now seems to go against how rails is designed to work but you might be able to put the following in your create action:

```
@user = current_user
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@user.twilio_account_sid, @user.twilio_auth_token)

search_params = {}
  %w[in_postal_code near_number contains].each do |p|
    search_params[p] = params[p] unless params[p].nil? || params[p].empty?
  end

local_numbers = client.account.available_phone_numbers.get('US').local
@numbers = local_numbers.list(search_params)
render 'find_numbers/show'
```

Also remember that you have the object @numbers so in your show view you'll have to do an each loop like:

```
<% @numbers.each do |number| %>
  <%= number.friendly_name %>
  <%= number.phone_number %>
<% end %>
```

I don't know anything about Twilio so I can't check over your use of their API.

Comment: Thunkele, you are amazing! I didn't know the variables persisted between views (i.e if I defined @numbers in the create action, it wouldn't show up in the show action).

With your suggestion, it's working! I'll also get the book you suggested.