# NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Api::SurveyAnswersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    # @survey_answer = SurveyAnswer.new(survey_answer_params)
    survey_answers = []
    survey_id = params[:survey_id]
    params[:questions].each do |q|
      answer = {survey_id: survey_id, option_ids: [], question_id: q[:id], 
                title: q[:answer]}
      if q[:options].present?
        selected_options = q[:answer].split(',')
        selected_options.each do |selected_option|
          q[:options].each do |option|
            if option[:title]== selected_option
              answer[:option_ids] << option[:id]
              #<todo add break when in this condition
            end
          end
        end
        survey_answers << answer
      end
    end

    puts survey_answers
    # @survey_answers = SurveyAnswer.create(survey_answers)
    if SurveyAnswer.create(survey_answers)
    render json: survey_answers
    end
  end
end
```

I have a survey model which has some questions. Each question contains answers. When I try to hit post request through postman to insert answers, it gives 505 internal server error with message "undefined method each for nil:nilclass". Can anybody tell what the problem is?

Comment: You need to show the backtrace.

Comment: `params[:questions]` is probably `nil` (though I can't be sure without the backtrace).

Comment: @MarekLipka yes when i do binding pry than params[:questions] is nil but in model there are 2 questions in that survey

Comment: @ShahrozAshraf are you passing them as param? can you post more context - for example the view code?

Comment: in params i am passing question_id survey_id like this..it has no view...
this is api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run the **.each** loop an empty object.

Make sure that both

```
params[:questions]
```

and

```
q[:options]
```

are not empty (not equal to *nil*).

**NoMethodError** sometimes sounds very unrepresentative, especially if you're just starting off with Ruby.

Try to browse Stackoverflow next time, because this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709204/nomethoderror-undefined-method-each-for-nilnilclass?rq=1).

Comment: yes when i do binding pry than params[:questions] is nil but in model there are 2 questions in that survey model

Comment: I assume that you're submitting some sort of a form then. Make sure you allow the parameters that you are passing through. Otherwise, they could be **nil** even if you enter them.

Comment: key                       value
                            
survey_id             1
question_id          32
title                       test


this is how i am giving parameters in postman

Comment: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 377041ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


  
NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
  
app/controllers/api/survey_answers_controller.rb:8:in `create'

Comment: Well, then you're trying to loop through `params[:questions]` while supplying only `params[:question_id]`.

By looking at your code, I would suggest passing a hash with all of the questions instead of a single **question_id** parameter.

Comment: i need to change in code or should i change the way of passing parameters in postman?

Comment: It completely depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you don't want to change the code, try passing a hash called **questions** where you have all of the questions with their respective ids, survey_ids, titles, etc. Otherwise, you'll have to adjust the code itself so it handles one question at a time.

Comment: thanks that error was solved..now i'm getting question id as well..
but now new error occurs
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):

Comment: That's a different problem altogether. Try to make sure that you're passing the right datatypes. It currently seems that you're trying to do something on a *Symbol* what is meant to be done on *Integer*. So either try to post a new question or spend some time debugging.